# findByForeign key in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have added a foreign key as such:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private UserEntity userEntity;
```

And my table has these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `web_course` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coursename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_entity_user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK6eys4s4qx87rxo0ha68q05oc8` (`user_entity_user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK6eys4s4qx87rxo0ha68q05oc8` FOREIGN KEY (`user_entity_user_id`) REFERENCES `web_user` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I would like to create a method to findByUserId in:

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<CourseEntity, Long> {
```

I have tried several combinations in vain:

```
public CourseEntity findByUserId(int user_id)
public CourseEntity findByUserEntityUserId(int user_id)
public CourseEntity findBy_User_entity_user_id(int user_id)
```

I read that there is a naming convention but I can't seem to find the correct convention since I am getting:

```
Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'courseRepository';
```

Course class:

```
package com.finaly.projectback.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "web_course")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CourseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    public UserEntity getUserEntity() {
        return userEntity;
    }

    public void setUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {
        this.userEntity = userEntity;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "coursename")
    private String coursename;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public CourseEntity() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCoursename() {
        return coursename;
    }

    public void setCoursename(String coursename) {
        this.coursename = coursename;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public CourseEntity(UserEntity userEntity, long id, String coursename, String description) {
        super();
        this.userEntity = userEntity;
        this.id = id;
        this.coursename = coursename;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CourseEntity [userEntity=" + userEntity + ", id=" + id + ", coursename=" + coursename + ", description="
                + description + "]";
    }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Could you add your Course class?

Comment: Yes, I just edited my question to add the class.

Comment: Can you post whole error log? Normally, it would tell you why it cannot create the CourseEntity?

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work:

```java
public CourseEntity findByUserEntity_UserId(int user_id)
```

Check logs to see if the course repository is instantiated or not. Error indicates controller can'be created because of the dependency issue.

Error creating bean with name `courseController`: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field `courseRepository`

Comment: I added the method as you mentioned and now getting the error: 

Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'courseRepository';

Should I add anything else for it to work please?

Comment: Is your repositiry in the same package or atleast in same package or sub package of main application class? Turn logging to ALL and see if repository is instantiated or not. It does not look like it us.

Comment: yes
com.finaly.projectBack

com.finaly.projectBack.controller

com.finaly.projectBack.entity

com.finaly.projectBack.repository.

When you say logging to all, you mean this? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging

Comment: Yes, logging.level.root=ALL

Comment: I added it to my application.properties but in the console I'm getting: 
Cannot set level 'ALL' for 'null'

I have added this dependency commons-logging and then removed it to add this one spring-boot-starter-log4j2 but still getting the same message

Comment: For the time being, remove all logging exclusions or dependencies you added in pom.xml. starter web comes with needed dependencies
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>